# What is the best way to optimize live website thumbnails?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Background: I'm creating a web design portfolio of sites I've created and like the effect I can get by doing live thumbnails because certain pages are dynamic and it's nice to show that at a glance without needing to open up each page. Additionally it is nice as these sites on my portfolio are constantly updated and I don't want to keep taking new thumbnail pictures of the site.

Question: What is the best way to optimize the code? Currently it's loading a full dozen web pages on one website. Is there an easy way to only load that first view of the site? Anyway to load the site scaled better so it doesn't load the full screen view of a site and scale it down? I'd like to cut down on the portfolio page load times if possible. I also understand this may be an unorthodox way to do what I'm trying to do so if there is a better way to get this concept in action I'd love any suggestions.

CSS Code:

```
/***************************/
/***** LIVE THUMBNAILS *****/
.pa-live-thumbnail iframe {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 768px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.pa-live-thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  -ms-zoom: 0.2;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(0.2);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.pa-live-thumbnail-container {
  width: calc(1280px * 0.2);
  height: calc(768px * 0.2);
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.pa-live-thumbnail-container a {
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; 
  left:0; 
  right:0; 
  bottom:0;   
  width: 1440px;
  height: 900px; 
  z-index:10;
}
.pa-live-thumbnail-container:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  content: "Loading thumbnail...";
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="pa-live-thumbnail-container">
  <div class="pa-live-thumbnail">
    <iframe src="http://pa-lib.com" onload="this.style.opacity = 1"></iframe>
    <a href="http://pa-lib.com"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's only so much you can do. 12 + 1 pages @ an average 40 - if the pages are coded well - `http` requests each means **more than 500 http requests** firing at the same time. I would not load the live websites. Just load static thumbnails then use JS to make AJAX requests on thumbnail hover. You can preload the preview sites at the footer of your main site for increased performance but that's limited to one so as to limit abuse. However, you might be able to come up with a hacky method to chain-preload the sites from within the iframes.

Comment: @I haz kode, very true. It's probably too many requests to be realistic. So basically when they hover have the thumbnail load the dynamic view so only one site is going at a time?

Comment: That's more or less the idea, the static thumbnail would look exactly like the live page, once the user hovers, the live preview is loaded behind the image and then the image disappears. It should be very smooth with 0 jitters since the site is loaded inside the frame but behind the image and since the image is pretty much the same view, when you start scrolling you would not notice a difference. However, it might be a bit tedious to code all of this. Another example you might want to look at is the way it's done on codepen's main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking @I has kode's answer as the best option to get the effect I want. However for simplicities sake I've realized it's just not a good option to get live thumbnails and have gone back to static images for now. I'll keep this on file though when I come back to this.